# Repetitive solution in Prolog

Tags: loops, prolog, duplicates, infinite, repeat

I have a piece of code that goes somewhat like this

```
call(Person, Someone) :-
    canCall(Person, Someone, []).

canCall(Person, Someone, _) :-
    hasNumber(Person, Someone).
canCall(Person, Someone, Contacted) :-
    personExists(SomeoneElse),
    \+ member(SomoneElse, Contacted),
    knows(SomeoneElse, Someone),
    canCall(Person, SomeoneElse, [Someone | Contacted]).
```

(knows checks for stuff like if they live close together, if they work together and etc. It definitely returns the right results and terminates.)

The code just gives the default solutions (for the first clause) and a single repeated solution for the second clause when I run this query

```
?- call(david, Someone).
```

and search for all alternative solutions. It is not just giving duplicate solutions. In fact, I wouldn't mind if I had duplicate solutions. It's just outputting one answer repeatedly though.

I'm not sure where the problem lies even after performing a trace.

Comment: If there are many ways two people can know each other and many ways a Person can call SomeoneElse, there will be _many × many_ ways a Person can call Someone.

Comment: Could you perhaps add some sample facts and output?

Comment: Also, you _do_ have a typo in `\+ member(SomoneElse, Contacted),`; you want "Som**E**oneElse"

Comment: You might want to avoid defining a predicate with such a generic name as `call` since `call` is already a pre-defined Prolog predicate.

Comment: Why `personExists(SomeoneElse)`? This is definitely superfluous.

Comment: This is not the exact code since I can't disclose that, but that's the idea. That's why there are some typo and whatnot. And (I hope) `personExists(SomeoneElse)` helps speed things up, since it's not going to check whether everyone fits with the `knows(SomeoneElse, Someone)`.

Comment: What's keeping you from posting the actual code? You **do** acknowledge that there may be problems in the fake code that do not exist in the actual code ...

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why, but

```
call(Person, Someone) :-
    canCall(Person, Someone, []).

canCall(Person, Someone, _) :-
    hasNumber(Person, Someone).
canCall(Person, Someone, Contacted) :-
    personExists(SomeoneElse),
    \+ member(SomoneElse, Contacted),
    canCall(Person, SomeoneElse, [Someone | Contacted]),
    knows(SomeoneElse, Someone).
```

worked. This is not my original code, so there's probably some other underlying reason (this example actually worked without the change).

Comment: @repeat: Well, since it terminates and finds all the right answers, I'm assuming it works...